3-clue 5x5 Hidato
Rules

Fill the grid with numbers 1-25 such that consecutive numbers are adjacent orthogonally or diagonally


Try solving it in Penpa
There are only about a dozen 5x5 Hidatos with only 3 clues.
(spoiler)

This one was tough!  I managed to solve it mostly through trial and error.  The vertical section between 16 and 22 is very constrained, because it needs quite a few sequences to pass through it, and there is only barely enough room.
I kept trying different ways of doing it until I eventually found one that worked:

 

